# XSS Filter not working in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, xss

I was trying XSS attack in IE11 to check whether it can prevent XSS or not. I noticed that it was not able to prevent XSS even when its "XSS Filter" was enabled. Why does this happens? Is there any bug in it or am i missing something that i should have done? Is there anyway to get over this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things, here is a post about it and a part that stood out to me that might be applicable:

[https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/internet-explorer-xss-filter/](https://web.archive.org/web/20171109123044/https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/internet-explorer-xss-filter/)

> In the simplest possible terms, the problem is that the anti-XSS filter only compares the untrusted request from the user and the response body from the website for reflections that could cause immediate JavaScript or VBScript code execution. Should an injection from that initial request reflect on the page not cause immediate JavaScript code execution, that untrusted data from the injection is then marked as trusted data, and the anti-XSS filter will not check it in future requests.

Comment: But it is not able to prevent even the simplest attack vector such as `<script>alert("Hello");</script>`. According to the documentation i have studied about XSS Filter, it does regular expression matching on the user input and therefore, should be able to prevent the execution of this script.

Comment: You can try it in your IE browser and check whether XSS Filter really works or not.

Comment: With respect, Carlos Munoz implied that IE authors overlooked the chance of a nested reflection where APP's reflected parameter PARAM's payload such as `PARAM=<a href="APP?PARAM=..."></a>` or `PARAM=<iform src="APP?PARAM=...">` gets decoded by the browser on clicking the reflected link`<a href="APP?PARAM=.."></a>` or on browser's re-interpreting the nested `<iform src="APP?PARAM=...">` page. https://web.archive.org/web/20171109123044/https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/internet-explorer-xss-filter/ My experiment shows that IE11 either checks multiple decoding or sees reflection of HTML entities.